# SignalR scaleout with Azure for chat scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, signalr-backplane

For a chat application, I use Azure architecture with SignalR, with the web-role acting as SignalR server (the messages are not broadcast type but are intended for specific user/client).

I want to scale out SignalR server along with the web-roles, to handle heavy user load. Although, SignalR documentation doesn't recommend to use the pre-baked SignalR scale out methods using backplane (Redis, Service bus) for such cases when the number of messages increase as more users are connected (or in user-event driven scenario). It explicitly states: *"Client-to-client (e.g., chat): In this scenario, the backplane might be a bottleneck if the number of messages scales with the number of clients; that is, if the rate of messages grows proportionally as more clients join."*

**Question:**
Does anyone know of any custom scale-out solution for such high-frequency case, which doesn't push messages to each server instance or some other scale-out solution?

Already looked everywhere in SignalR documentation and the related videos but couldn't find anything, other than a word "filtered-bus", which was not explained what it is and how it should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself: Basic idea is server affinity/sticky sessions.

Each instance of web-role acts as a stand-alone SignalR server. At the first connection time, I let the Azure load balancer choose any instance of web-role and save the IP address of that web-role instance with the client identifier in a map. If there is another connect request coming from the same client (e.g after page refresh) then I check the IP address of the current role instance and if it matches the entry in map then I let it proceed otherwise I disconnect the client and connects it to the correct instance of web-role.

Each instance of worker-role also acts as SignalR .net client and connects to all the available SignalR servers (all instances of web-role). Before sending a message to the SignalR server (web-role), I look up in the map to determine the correct SignalR server instance (depending on the intended JS recipient).

**Benefits**:

- There is no need of back-plane technology (and hence no delays in message delivery).
- Each web-role instance care about the client connected to it and each message doesn't have to be duplicated on every SignalR server. Hence it can scale pretty good.
- Easy to implement.

Comment: *"disconnect the client and connects it to the correct instance of web-role."* How did you achieve that in Azure? Say you have 4 role instances, how do you redirect the client to connect to the correct instance? The instances only have a private IP, so we cannot redirect based on a public IP. Also we can't keep rejecting the requests to other instances in case the IP addr doesn't match. What would happen in case the server is restarted or worse, re-imaged? Would appreciate if you could give a little more details.